# Return the sum of the product of columns in different tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, analytics, dashboard, powerbi-desktop

I have 3 tables in PowerBI with columns below, for different systems:

- **Platform 1:** [Date, Sub_System, ticket_number]
- **Platform 2:** [Date,Sub_System, ticket_number]
- **Standard_time_by_system:** [System, Sub_system, multiplier]

I need to group by date the product of count of ticket_number and the multiplier by subsystem, which then gives the total by system

The error I'm having is that the total by **system** returns the total count of tickets * sum of multiplier by system, not the sum of the iteration of ticket_number * multiplier.

Example:

Platform 2

| Date | Sub_system | ticket_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | Sub_system 1 | 100001 |
| 1/2/2022 | Sub_system 2 | 100003 |

Platform 1

| Date | Sub_system | ticket_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | Sub_system 1 | 100004 |
| 1/2/2022 | Sub_system 2 | 100005 |

standard_time_by_system

| System | Sub_system | multiplier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| System 1 | Sub system 1 | 5 |
| System 1 | Sub system 2 | 3 |
| System 2 | Sub system 3 | 7 |
| System 2 | Sub system 4 | 6 |

I need

| System | Sub system | count(ticket_number)*multiplier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| System 1 | Sub system 1 | 10 |
| System 1 | Sub system 2 | 6 |
| **System 1 total** |  | 16 |

I'm getting

| System | Sub system | count(ticket_number)*multiplier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| System 1 | Sub system 1 | 10 |
| System 1 | Sub system 2 | 6 |
| **System 1 total** |  | 32 |

Hope the example works a bit, I'm doing something like the below but it returns the wrong result again first adding the multipliers and not doin the iteration

````
        ISFILTERED('Standard_time_by_system'[System]),
            (COUNTA('Platform 1'[sub_system])+COUNTA('Platform 1'[sub_system]))*SUM('Standard_time_by_system'[multiplier]),
            SUMX('Standard_time_by_system'[System],Standard_time_by_system[multiplier]*COUNTA('Role Management Tracker'[System])))```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your Total is calculated by the second part of the IF statement, where you use additional table 'Role Management Tracker'[System] (not described);

```
SUMX('Standard_time_by_system'[System],Standard_time_by_system[multiplier]*COUNTA('Role Management Tracker'[System]))
```

you should check this part;